# Creating POSIX Threads in a loop

Tags: multithreading, posix

If I create POSIX threads in a loop. Will the threads start running according to the order of creation?

Comment: maybe..maybe not.. You can't say. It depends on the main thread, invoking of sleep methods, and the OS scheduler controlling the various processes currently running and context-switching between them.

Comment: Ok thx, I will think about it

Comment: @vishakvkt, your comment is probably the best answer this question is going to get.   Why not convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is what Vishakvkt already said: Posix threads offers no guarantees on how they will be scheduled. If you need thread n+1 to depend somehow on thread n, you need to have them rendezvous on some sort of synchronization object, like a mutex or a condition variable.